# Custom image in Local Notification

Tags: ios

How can I set custom app icon or image for Local Notifications in iOS 8?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

According to Apple's HIG on [Notifications](https://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/NotificationCenter.html),

> iOS displays your notification message and the small version of your app icon.

I believe this is the 29x29 size that is recommended for the Settings search results. For more details on the different app icon sizes, you can view the HIG document on [Icon and Image Sizes](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/MobileHIG/IconMatrix.html).

Comment: I want to use an image other than my app icon. Is it possible to do so?

Comment: I don't believe so - the purpose of that image is so users will be able to determine which application is sending the notification to them. I suppose though if you REALLY want to cheat this process, you can try to just upload a different icon in the 29x29 app icon spot in your project...